# Play youtube video in Background using YouTube Helper Library iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, youtube, youtube-api

Im using YouTube Helper Library to play YouTube videos on my iOS application
[Here are link of Library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper)
I just need a way to continue audio (or video) playing in background ,
So when user click on home button i need him to be able to hear the voice
of the video ,
even when he lock his device i need to him to be able to control the sound and 
click next and back button for audio playing ..
How i can achieve that on YouTube Helper Library ?

**NOTE: many application do that and they exist on app-store like iMusic , Video Tube ,MusicTV , MB2**

Comment: the above lib uses `webview` to play video .i don't think there is a way to play video in background until you make a custom video player.[link](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2011/04/background-audio-through-ios-movie.html)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About playing sounds in background:

You have to set the AVAudioSession category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback and add the audio value to the UIBackgroundModes key in your information property list file.

```
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];
```

I have tested this code on iOS 7 and up only, so it may not work for earlier versions.

From Apple docs:

> AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback The category for playing recorded music
>   or other sounds that are central to the successful use of your app.
>
> When using this category, your app audio continues with the Silent
>   switch set to silent or when the screen locks. (The switch is called
>   the Ring/Silent switch on iPhone.) To continue playing audio when your
>   app transitions to the background (for example, when the screen
>   locks), add the audio value to the UIBackgroundModes key in your
>   information property list file.

see references [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html)

Comment: are you sure this will work with YouTube Helper Library ?
i know this is the solution if we wanna to play a mp3 file ..etc , 
i try it but it dose not works for me for this library .. any suggestion ??

Comment: I am using exactly this library and for my app it is working with these settings. Also I have added to info plist for Required background modes: App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay. I am setting the category in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and it just works, if I remove it - it stops working.

Comment: ok cool i will try it , but tell me please can the user click next and back buttons and everything working well , i mean when the screen locked or when the app in background ??

Comment: It is working in background home/lock, with one flaw - it kind of pauses for half a second and then plays normally. The control buttons are usable, but you should handle the actions.
When you press a button in background, the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` is being called with a status code (0 – video ended) in the `request.URL`. If you handle the delegate method `playerView:didChangeToState:`, you can implement the desired behavior.
I am not sure how you can get the exact button that is pressed,
because this is not key in my app and I have not searched for a solution.

Comment: BTW , controling next and back button on lock mood or background mood can bde don via this function    
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Comment: Thanks! I may use it in the future.

Comment: @Adel never ask if something will work or not without trying it out **yourself** first

Comment: @DesislavaS it would be very nice if you actually provided a link to the apple docs you referenced above

Comment: @abbood what is your problem !

Comment: @abbood i do not know what you are talking about !!

Answer (score 4):

Playing background video (or voice) is against the [YouTube TOS](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms). You can not do it with this library for sure, even if you figure out a workaround, your app would be taken down because of TOS violation.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but many apps do that , search app store for the following applications ... iMusic , Video Tube ,MusicTV , MB2 
all these applications play youtube video in background ..
any suggestions ??

Comment: @Ibrahim Ulukaya never give us a generic link to some terms of service page.. for two reasons: 1. where exactly does the OP's intended result violate the terms of service? (couldn't find it myself) 2. terms of services change all the time..

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable it when app enter background. Remember to check your app is in background

```
func playerView(_ playerView: YTPlayerView, didChangeTo state: YTPlayerState) {
    if state == .paused {
        playerView.playVideo()
    }
}
```